# How to filter usb devices to be used for certain vendor or device id in windows?

Tags: windows-7, usb, regedit, gpo, winusb

I want to limit usb ports on a windows 7 machine by only allowing specific usb vendor or device id. I am not managing a group of computers so I do not want to use group policy or sth. like that.. I just want to deny all usb devices to be used for all users on the machine except certain usb devices that I want to allow according to their vendor or product id. Thank you